# Create an mask for progress drawable on Custom Progress Bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

[image: Progress examples]

I'm creating a custom progress bar like number (2) on picture. But I can't make round corners on the start of progress bar (like you can see it). I'm using images for background and progress drawable.

The progress bar (1) is what I want to make, but with images. What I have to do for my progress bar (2) been like (1), but with images?

NOTE: On progress bar (1) i'm using de default of Android:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        /> 
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ffffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#ffffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ffffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Comment: what about trimming your image?

Comment: but in that way I have trimmindg on the back and front of image, and when the progress bar is in the middle of progress (e.g 50%), I want that progress be a vertical line, if you know what a I'm saying?

Comment: @DavidFortunato, could you post the layout file contains `<ProgressBar>`? After I apply the `android:progressDrawable` to my `<ProgressBar>` I can't see the progress because the progress value keeps its max. value.